# use different glibc version

Tags: python, glibc, epoll

Currently I have glibc which does not support epoll, so I installed new glibc at non default lation which supports epoll. I have python program which uses this epoll.

I tried to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/glibc/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

then I run ls, it gave me errors

`ls: /home/glibc/lib/tls/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /lib/libpam.so.0)`

`ls: /home/glibc/lib/tls/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /lib/libpam_misc.so.0)`

Also when I tried to run python I got

`python: relocation error: /home/glibc/lib/tls/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_out_of_memory, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux.so.2 with link time reference`

How can I use newly installed glibc instead of default one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an explicit invocation of the dynamic linker, so something like this:

```
/home/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /home/glibc/lib /usr/bin/python
```

(But the fact that the `GLIBC_2.4` symbol version is not available suggests that something is very wrong with the new glibc, or it is actually not very new at all, predating glibc 2.4.)

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled glibc yourself you should have testrun.sh script in your build directory. This is simpler and more reliable than using ld-linux.so:

```
build/testrun.sh ls
```